# how to extract an array var value in smarty w/o foreach

Tags: multidimensional-array, smarty

When print out an array (complex) within Smarty (printing from {$myarray->get_fields()|print_r}, I get the following list:

```
Array
(
[44] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 44
        [name] => Address 2
        [type] => textbox
        [max_length] => 255
        [create_date] => 2013-03-25 10:02:02
        [modified_date] => 2013-03-25 10:02:02
        [item_order] => 
        [admin_only] => 0
        [public] => 1
        [dropdown_data] => 
        [data] => 
        [fielddef_id] => 44
        [value] => Halifax
    )

[47] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 47
        [name] => Address 3
        [type] => textbox
        [max_length] => 255
        [create_date] => 2013-03-25 10:02:56
        [modified_date] => 2013-03-25 10:02:56
        [item_order] => 
        [admin_only] => 0
        [public] => 1
        [dropdown_data] => 
        [data] => 
        [fielddef_id] => 47
    )

[50] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 50
        [name] => Address 4
        [type] => textbox
        [max_length] => 255
        [create_date] => 2013-03-25 10:03:40
        [modified_date] => 2013-03-25 10:03:40
        [item_order] => 
        [admin_only] => 0
        [public] => 0
        [dropdown_data] => 
        [data] => 
        [fielddef_id] => 50
    )
)
```

I want to print out directly print the [value] field of the first array in set in the array (44). Basically, I'm wanting to print [44]->name, but not sure how I can do that directly without iterating through a foreach loop with a series of if/else statements.

Comment: `$array_name[44]['name']` or `$array_name[44]->name` will work.

Comment: @deadlock, thank you so much for that - I've been running low on hair trying to get that sorted! The second version is the one that did the trick for me (using CMS Made Simple - Company Directory module). `$array_name[44]->name` Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### As simple as:

```
$array_name[44]['name']
```

### Or

```
$array_name[44]->name
```